# How to show a list of random image via click event?

Tags: javascript, html

I have coded a basic php web page where I want random images from my images folder to be displayed once a button has been clicked.

However no images are being displayed and I cannot find the issue with my code.

```js
var myImg = ["fruit1.jpg", "fruit2.jpg", "fruit3.jpg", "fruit4.jpg", "fruit5.jpg", "fruit6.jpg"];

function displayImage() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  document.picture.src = myImg[num];
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="boxa">A1
    <input onclick="displayImage();" type=button value="Display Random Image">
    <img src="" name="picture" />
  </div>
  <div class="boxb">B
    <input onclick="displayImage();" type=button value="Display Random Image">
    <img src="" name="picture" />
  </div>
  <div class="boxc">C
    <input onclick="displayImage();" type=button value="Display Random Image">
    <img src="" name="picture" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: quite possible image is not at src path. Is image in same path as html?

Comment: @James sorry I have edited the post so its just for one specific question :)

Comment: @Stakshi Yeah they both have the same path and relate to the same folder! That is what is getting me confused

Comment: As I got no reply I deleted my answer.

Comment: Apologies, your answer was correct! I haven't been on here for a couple day

Answer (score 0):

`document.picture.src` **doesn't exist**.

When you click on the `<input>`, you want to access the `<img ...>` and that's the **nextElementSibling**. Therefore, you need an **argument** in the function, too.

#### Example

```js
var myImg = ["fruit1.jpg", "fruit2.jpg", "fruit3.jpg", "fruit4.jpg", "fruit5.jpg", "fruit6.jpg"];

function displayImage(el) {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  el.nextElementSibling.src = myImg[num];
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="boxa">A1
    <input onclick="displayImage(this);" type=button value="Display Random Image">
    <img src="" name="picture" />
  </div>
  <div class="boxb">B
    <input onclick="displayImage(this);" type=button value="Display Random Image">
    <img src="" name="picture" />
  </div>
  <div class="boxc">C
    <input onclick="displayImage(this);" type=button value="Display Random Image">
    <img src="" name="picture" />
  </div>
</div>
```

### A better generic solution would be

```js
var myImg = ["fruit1.jpg", "fruit2.jpg", "fruit3.jpg", "fruit4.jpg", "fruit5.jpg", "fruit6.jpg"];
var selector = "div[class^=box] input";

function El(selector) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}

function setRandImg(img, images) {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  img.src = images[rand];
}

function addEventListeners(els, type, fn) {
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i += 1) {
    var el = els[i];
    el.addEventListener(type, fn);
  }
}

function displayImg() {
  setRandImg(this.nextElementSibling, myImg);
}

addEventListeners(El(selector), "click", displayImg);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="boxa">A1
    <input type=button value="Display Random Image">
    <img src="" name="picture" />
  </div>
  <div class="boxb">B
    <input type=button value="Display Random Image">
    <img src="" name="picture" />
  </div>
  <div class="boxc">C
    <input type=button value="Display Random Image">
    <img src="" name="picture" />
  </div>
</div>
```